# Search fields In sencha touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

In my app I have to add Search field and some select fields.
when I add any character in search field corresponding content from store should be display.
Currently I am using search field  on which I am handling **keyup** event.
Please let me know the flow and guide line to do this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you want a search feature for your search field..showing the results as you type. You can achieve this by using regular expressions and compare them with entries in the store.

Here's the code I used on a project:

```
      //referencing my searchfield
 Search: '#searchfield';
      //attaching an event
 Search: {
            keyup: "OnFocus"
         }
      //the actual function 
OnFocus: function (searchField, e) {
   var query = searchField.getValue(); //get the value entered in the search field
   var  ContactsContainer = this.getContactsContainer(); //the container that holds my contacts
   var store = Ext.getStore('Contacts'); // the store where I have the info
   store.clearFilter(); //assure there aren't any filters set

    if (query) {  //if the current value in the search field
       var thisRegEx = new RegExp(query, 'i'); //new regular expression with our value
       store.filterBy(function (record) {      //filter the store 
           if (thisRegEx.test(record.get('name')) //the fields in the store
               thisRegEx.test(record.get('surname'))
               thisRegEx.test(record.get('phone'))) {
               return true;  //must include this
           };


            return false;
       });
   }
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi **Bogdan** my concern is if I a using current code in same form using listeners and keyup event means not in controller then  what should be in record..

Comment: You just use your store name that you created with your data and don't worry about the record